# Angular 2 getting only the dirty values in a controlgroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form in Angular 2 that works with a custom ControlGroup. At the moment, when I submit my form, I pass all the data with the following line to my controller.

```
(ngSubmit)="updateArtist(artistDetailForm.value)"
```

The problem is that this passes all values of a form, and if my forms are quite large this feels quite useless. Is there a possibility to only pass the modified (dirty?) values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the new changes to the Angular Forms I've slightly modified the accepted answer, so it works. Decided to share if anyone is interested. (using Angular 4+)

```
getDirtyValues(form: any) {
        let dirtyValues = {};

        Object.keys(form.controls)
            .forEach(key => {
                const currentControl = form.controls[key];

                if (currentControl.dirty) {
                    if (currentControl.controls)
                        dirtyValues[key] = this.getDirtyValues(currentControl);
                    else
                        dirtyValues[key] = currentControl.value;
                }
            });

        return dirtyValues;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Declare your form.

```ts
this.artistDetailForm= formBuilder.group({......});
```

Define a function to extract values on submit

```ts
// feed me controlGroups

getDirtyValues(cg) {
  let dirtyValues = {};  // initialize empty object
  Object.keys(cg.controls).forEach((c) => {

     let currentControl = cg.find(c);

     if(currentControl.dirty){
        if(currentControl.controls) //check for nested controlGroups
           dirtyValues[c] = getDirtyValues(currentControl);  //recursion for nested controlGroups
        else    
           dirtyValues[c] = currentControl.value;  //simple control
     }

    });
  return dirtyValues;
}
```

and then do this

```ts
(ngSubmit)="updateArtist(getDirtyValues( artistDetailForm ))"
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UfCadkBNzD0XMopQIXSg?p=preview)

Comment: For Angular 6, you can use `let currentControl = controlGroups.get(c);` to replace  `let currentControl = cg.find(c);` if it gives you an error.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a version that traverse an arbitrary Form structure and gives you the changed values in a nested Map-like structure. Meaning the returned dirty values will be at the same level as the dirty control.

```
getDirtyValues(
  form: FormGroup | FormArray | FormControl | AbstractControl
): Map<string, any> | any[] | any | undefined {
  if (!form.dirty) {
    return;
  }

  if (form instanceof FormControl) {
    return form.value;
  }

  if (form instanceof FormGroup) {
    const result = new Map();
    for (const [key, control] of Object.entries(form.controls)) {
      const nestedResult = this.getDirtyValues(control);
      if (nestedResult) {
        result.set(key, this.getDirtyValues(control));
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  if (form instanceof FormArray) {
    const result = new Array();
    form.controls.forEach(control => {
      const nestedResult = this.getDirtyValues(control);
      if (nestedResult) {
        result.push(nestedResult);
      }
    });

    return result;
  }

  throw new Error('Form must be a FromGroup, FormArray or FormControl.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is more comprehensive as it takes into account FormArray.