# How to send only the changed part of the form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have a form group and then I map the values on the form to my object type to make a request to edit the item.

Form:

```
  public companyForm = new FormGroup(
    {
      generalInfo: new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(this.maxLength)]),
        active: new FormControl(false)
      }),
      address: new FormGroup({
        street: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(this.maxLength)]),
        streetNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        postalCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        country: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      })
   })
```

CompanyEdit object:

```
      name: formValue.generalInfo.name,
      active: formValue.generalInfo.active,
      address: {
        street: formValue.address.street,
        city: formValue.address.city,
        streetNumber: formValue.address.streetNumber,
        postalCode: formValue.address.postalCode
      },
      country: formValue.address.country
```

The fields names and the way they are nested are not compatible. While editing, I like to send only the changed controls on the form. What would be the best way to achieve acquiring the dirty controls and map them to my object type?

Answer (score 0):

You can check form if there is a dirty values in formGroup.

There is a answer from similar question on stackoverflow [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342444/angular-2-getting-only-the-dirty-values-in-a-controlgroup). I will copy/paste the code here for you.

```
  getDirtyValues(form: any) {
        let dirtyValues = {};

        Object.keys(form.controls)
            .forEach(key => {
                const currentControl = form.controls[key];

                if (currentControl.dirty) {
                    if (currentControl.controls)
                        dirtyValues[key] = this.getDirtyValues(currentControl);
                    else
                        dirtyValues[key] = currentControl.value;
                }
            });

        return dirtyValues;
}
```